# Trying to compile a file and open it for edit if it fails or run it if it goes through

Tags: bash

So I have written this line of Bash

```
rustc hello.rs && ./hello || ( exit_on_error sleep 10s ; vi hello.rs )
```

The goal is that I compile the file. If compilation is successful it should run the script. If not it should give me 10 seconds to read the error before opening the file for edit again.

I have been having trouble getting the sleep and the edit to happen sequentially and only when the compilation fails. I cant figure out what type of bracket to use. In this version if compilation fails it immediately opens the file for edit.

How can I achieve the desired result here?

Comment: Regarding "I cant figure out what type of bracket to use", the `( )` you're using creates a [subshell](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), which is probably not what you want. `{ }` is simply a grouping operator. See [The Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't waste time trying to understand the interactions of multiple sequential `&&` and `||` operations (especially not in a mixture — all the same is OK).  I'd just write it cleanly:

```
if rustc hello.rs
then ./hello
else sleep 10s; vi hello.rs
fi
```

which can be flattened onto a single line with:

```
if rustc hello.rs; then ./hello; else sleep 10s; vi hello.rs; fi
```

But I'd make it into a script which takes the file name(s) as arguments and processes them, etc, with environment variables to adjust the compiler and options too.